# Extjs Border Layout minSize center region not working

Tags: extjs, extjs3

Hi I have a given panel

I want the center region to have a fixed minSize.

```
Test.Grid.Panel = {
    id: 'test-grid-summary'
    ,layout: 'border'
    ,defaults: {
        collapsible: true
        ,split: true
        ,border: false
    },
    items: [
        {
            region: 'center'
            ,collapsible: false
            ,layout: 'fit'
            ,minSize: 100   // NOT WORKING
            ,items: [
            {
                xtype: 'test-Grid'
                ,id: 'grid-test'
            }
        ]
        },
        {
            region: 'south'
            ,id: 'panel-test'
            ,title: 'Test'
            ,height: 150
            ,minSize: 75
            ,layout: 'fit'
            ,plugins: [Ext.ux.PanelCollapsedTitle]                
        }
    ]
};
```

When I drag the south panel up it almost hides the center panel even though it has a minSize.

Please help me with the correct settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your container have size greater than 250 (which is sum of height of south panel and minimum height of center panel) then you can set `minHeight` property of center panel (instead of `minSize`) and splitter won't allow to set height less than that value.

Comment: VBox Layout does not have a splitter and I need resizeable panels. Can you suggest other options.

Comment: I've discovered that setting `minHeight` on center panel actually works. Try to set it instead of `minSize`